# What push notification technology will do what I want?

Tags: firebase, flutter, dart, push-notification, firebase-cloud-messaging

I'm writing a flutter app and want push notifications to be sent every 30 minutes based on data in firebase. I want the push notifications to send regardless of whether the app is open. The notifications would be specific to the user.

I looked into workmanager and backend_fetch and neither will run periodically in ios. https://github.com/transistorsoft/flutter_background_fetch/issues/32#issuecomment-673515924

Is there a way to do this using Firebase Cloud Messaging or Azure Push Notifications?

Comment: Which type of data in firebase are you actually talking about ?

Comment: Cloud Firestore database. It would be based on events coming up in the next 30 minutes

Answer (score 0):

I've discovered that yes this is possible using flutter server functions with FCM. I was able to set up a function to run every 30 minutes, query the firestore db and send messages to users using the stored FCM tokens.